# What's wrong with this program to add three numbers in an array to get 30

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to add together three odd numbers less than 15 to get 30.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class odd {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n[]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15};
        int a,n1,n2,n3;
        Random rand=new Random();

    do {
        n1=n[(rand.nextInt(8)+1)];
        n2=n[(rand.nextInt(8)+1)];
        n3=n[(rand.nextInt(8)+1)];
        a=n1+n2+n3;}while(a!=30);
        System.out.println(n1);
        System.out.println(n2);
        System.out.println(n3);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
>       at oddno.odd.main(odd.java:12)

Comment: No three numbers in that array sum to 30 though.

Comment: Please read the basics about [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array has 8 elements with indices from 0 to 7.

Therefore change

```
    n1=n[(rand.nextInt(8)+1)];
    n2=n[(rand.nextInt(8)+1)];
    n3=n[(rand.nextInt(8)+1)];
```

to

```
    n1=n[rand.nextInt(8)];
    n2=n[rand.nextInt(8)];
    n3=n[rand.nextInt(8)];
```

or as AxelH suggested:

```
    n1=n[rand.nextInt(n.length)];
    n2=n[rand.nextInt(n.length)];
    n3=n[rand.nextInt(n.length)];
```

Comment: Use **n.length** to be able to change de length of the table without having to go in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
int n[]={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15}; // size of array is 8
```

While you got index from `0` to `7`. There is not such element with index `8`.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is horrible. For starters, it will loop indefinitely if the sum is unattainable. Designing the algorithm is at least as important as the implementation. Consider some smarter approaches:

1. You could choose only two numbers at random, subtract those from the total and check if the resulting number is in the set. That might be slower though than drawing 3 numbers at random and computing the sum. Profile it.
2. It would be marginally better if you tried (systematically) all possible combinations of the three numbers.
3. Moving on, you can build up a "tree"-like structure of possibilities and eliminate branches quickly. For example, once you've drawn 1, you can't pick 3, 5, and so on. In this way you can progressively reduce the dimensionality of the problem until it becomes quite trivial.

As for your actual error, it's down to the fact that arrays in Java are zero-based: `n` ranges from `n[0]` to and including `n[7]`. If you *must* pick at random, then use `rand.nextInt(n.length)`.